# Angular-momentum of the Dirac spinor theory

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, dirac-equation, spinors, noethers-theorem

The standard Dirac action
$$
S = \int d^4 x \bar \psi (i \gamma^\mu \partial_\mu - m) \psi 
$$
is invariant under Lorentz transformation.

In David Tong's lecture note, eq (4.96) lists that the corresponding Noether current is
$$
(J^\mu)^{\rho \sigma} = x^\rho T^{\mu \sigma} - x^\sigma T^{\mu \rho} - i \bar \psi\gamma^\mu S^{\rho \sigma} \psi \ ,
$$
where $T$ is the conserved stress tensor and $S^{ab} \propto \gamma^a\gamma^b - \gamma^b \gamma^a$.

The first two terms clear conserve. However, I fail to show that the second term is conserved:
$$
\begin{align}
  \partial_\mu (\bar \psi i \gamma^\mu S^{\rho \sigma}\psi)
= & \ (\partial_\mu\bar \psi i \gamma^\mu S^{\rho \sigma}\psi) + (\bar \psi i \gamma^\mu S^{\rho \sigma}\partial_\mu\psi)\\
= & \ - m (\bar \psi S^{\rho \sigma}\psi) + (\bar \psi i \gamma^\mu S^{\rho \sigma}\partial_\mu\psi)\ .
\end{align}
$$
I'm not sure how to deal with the second term, since $\gamma^\mu$ sits away from $\partial_\mu$, and $\gamma$ does not simply commute with $S^{\rho \sigma}$.

**I wonder if there is some magical trick I should do or if the current is incorrect?**

Comment: In the spinor theoy only the total angular momentum $J=L+S$ is conserved.

Comment: The first two terms are conserved only if $T^{\mu\nu} = T^{\nu\mu}$ which is not true here (assuming $T$ is the canonical stress tensor, _not_ the Belinfante stress tensor).

Comment: @Prahar you are right, I mistaken the said $T$ with the symmetric one.